# Improper variable shadowing in swift

Tags: swift

so I'm reading the book app development by apple and I'm stuck on a challange, the challange is to check who took the most amount of steps from an array of users

```
func getWinner(competitors: [User]) -> User? {
    var topCompetitor: User?

    for competitor in competitors {
        if let topCompetitor = topCompetitor {
            if competitor.stepsToday > topCompetitor.stepsToday {
                topCompetitor = competitor
            }
        } else {
            topCompetitor = competitor
        }
    }
    return topCompetitor
}
```

The error I get is:

> Cannot assign to value: 'topCompetitor' is a 'let' constant

and the clue I get from the assignent is:

> The code generates a compiler error because, due to improper variable shadowing, topCompetitor has a narrower scope than it should if it is going to be reassigned.

Comment: Note that using this method or the max method suggested wouldn't consider the possibility of multiple winners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is on this line:

```
if let topCompetitor = topCompetitor {
```

With the `if let`, you have declared a new variable named `topCompetitor`. Since this variable has the same name as the `var` you've declared further up, that `var` is now *shadowed*, which means that it is no longer accessible since another variable has usurped its name.

You can work around this by declaring a different name in the `if let`, for example:

```
if let _topCompetitor = topCompetitor {
```

This way, you can use `_topCompetitor` to refer to the `let` variable you've declared here, and still use `topCompetitor` to refer to the `var`.

Alternately, you could ditch the whole for loop and use functional programming instead. Look up the handy `max(by:)` function, by which you could reduce your whole function to a one-liner.

Comment: But if I change the name of the variable then my topCompetitor is not unwrapped

Comment: It is unwrapped, as `_topCompetitor`.